# Java how to make argument a multiplication product of two other arguments?

Tags: java

I'm sure this is something of a noob question, but in a program I'm working on I am trying to pass a variable as an argument, which is easy enough, but I'm stuck because the variable I am trying to pass is a product of two arguments that come before it.

I have to create an object for a motorized vehicle that have arguments for the name of the vehicle owner, number of wheels, and the displacement in liters, but the forth and final argument is the result of multiplying the displacement and the number of wheels together, called "horsepower" (though I'm pretty sure this isn't how horsepower is really calculated.)

In any case, in a class that defines the "MotorizedVehicle" I have the following code.

```
    /*


public class MotorizedVehicle extends Bicycle {
    int litersDisplaced;
    int horsepower = litersDisplaced * wheelCount;




public MotorizedVehicle(String ownerName, int wheelCount, int litersDisplaced, int horsepower){
    this.ownerName = ownerName;
    this.wheelCount = wheelCount;
    this.litersDisplaced = litersDisplaced;
    this.horsepower = horsepower;

}

    public int getLitersDisplaced() {
        return litersDisplaced;
    }

    public void setLitersDisplaced(int litersDisplaced) {
        this.litersDisplaced = litersDisplaced;
    }

    public int getHorsepower() {
        return horsepower;
    }

    public void setHorsepower(int horsepower) {
        this.horsepower = horsepower;
    }
}
```

Now, in the client class I have the following code:

```
/*

package extracredit4;

/**
 *
 * @author ChetSpalsky
 */
public class VehicleClient {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MotorizedVehicle car1 = new MotorizedVehicle("Bill", 2, 4, *); //Where I have the * this is where the argument for the "horsepower" variable or method should be, but I don't know what to put here to call the variable that will be litersDisplaced * wheelCount.


}

}
```

To be clear, I can't just put "8" where that fourth argument should be, I have to call the method that multiplies litersDisplaced and wheelCount together.

Sorry if this is one of those questions that will just make an experienced programmer facepalm, but I've looked all over and can't seem to find the answer to this question, and I really appreciate the help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

just put 2 * 4, as in `MotorizedVehicle car1 = new MotorizedVehicle("Bill", 2, 4, 2 * 4);`

Answer (score 0):

For `horsepower` you can get rid of the argument altogether. Change the constructor to look like this:

```
public MotorizedVehicle(String ownerName, int wheelCount, int litersDisplaced){
    this.ownerName = ownerName;
    this.wheelCount = wheelCount;
    this.litersDisplaced = litersDisplaced;
    this.horsepower = this.litersDisplaced * this.wheelCount;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform the multiplication within the constructor:

```
public MotorizedVehicle(String ownerName, int wheelCount, int litersDisplaced){
    this.ownerName = ownerName;
    this.wheelCount = wheelCount;
    this.litersDisplaced = litersDisplaced;
    horsepower = wheelCount * litersDisplaced;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you not allowed omit the horsepower argument and calculate the horsepower value when you call `getHorsePower()`?  For example,

```
public MotorizedVehicle(String ownerName, int wheelCount, int litersDisplaced){
    this.ownerName = ownerName;
    this.wheelCount = wheelCount;
    this.litersDisplaced = litersDisplaced;
}

public int getHorsepower() {
    return wheelCount * litersDisplaced;
}
```

The nice thing about this approach, is if you call `setWheelCount()` or `setLitersDisplaced()`, the `getHorsePower()` function will always return the correct horsePower value.

You would want to remove the `setHorsepower()` function since it is a calculated value.